# Is it possible to introduce a scalar product (set the Gram matrix)

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations, transformation

Is it possible to introduce a scalar product (set the Gram matrix) so that the linear transformation given by the matrix $\pmatrix{3&2&-2\\0&2&1\\0&0&3}$ becomes normal?

Comment: What have you tried ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer is yes. $A$ is diagonalizable, so it suffices to select an eigenbasis of $A$ is and take the scalar product relative to which this basis is orthonormal.